# as3 text character to array element

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, text

I need to text character convert to array elements,

```
word.text="Hello";
```

I don't know how is convert

```
wordArray=["H","e","l","l","o"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic question and a search on google would have given you the right answer....
But anyway....

```
 wordArray = word.text.split('');
```

Comment: small typo - without last dot )